# Is there a way to batch delete users from cognito pool using lambda?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am using congnito to authenticate users to my app, and i have a crud where i can handle them one by one, but there are cases when i want to delete them all at once in a single batch operation.

The problem is that the docs say nothing about this and other A&Q sites say that there is not way for this.

I was thinking to use `Promise.all()` in an array of cognito clients to delete them in a single batch? but i don't know if it's possible or this may couse timeout in my lanmbda?

something like this i had in mind.

```
// const data = req.body.users;
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const CognitoIdentityServiceProvider = aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider;

const toDelete = [];
data.forEach((item) => {
    const client = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ apiVersion: '2016-04-19', region: 'us-east-1' });
    toDelete.push(cliente.adminDeleteUser(/* data */));
})
Promise.all(toDelete).then(() => { /* something */ });
```

Could this work? is bad practice? is there a better way?

Comment: You can do this, but be aware of potential for rate limiting on the API. The admin APIs in particular have low limits. The SDK includes retry logic that will handle some of that, but if the number of records is too large you're going to hit it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option without using the lambda functions is, if you have configured aws cli in windows, you can use the following script as a bat file to delete the users listed on a single page from the listing command output, repeat until all users are deleted.

You need to have JQ downloaded and its path added to system env path for the following to work.

---delete.bat---

@echo off
setlocal

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id $COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID ^| jq -r ".Users | .[] | .Username"') do (
aws cognito-idp admin-delete-user --user-pool-id $COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID --username %%I
echo %%I deleted
)

---delete.bat---